# Error uploading posts to a Wordpress database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

So I have this non wordpress database and I need to put all the posts in the Wordpress database, to do that I use this script but only uploads 1037 rows from 11231.

This is the script.

```
<?php
  ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); 
  require("connect.php");
  $conn = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","psswd");
  mysqli_select_db($conn,"db_test");
  $results = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM test");
  $i = 0;
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
  $post = array();
  $post['post_status'] = 'publish';
  $post['ID']=$row['idPost'];
  $post['post_date']=$row['date'];
  $post['post_date_gmt']=$row['date'];
  $post['post_content']=$row['body'];
  $post['post_title']=$row['title'];
  $posts[$i] = $post;
  $i++;
}
 mysqli_free_result($results);
 mysqli_close($conn);

 require('C:\xampp\htdocs\test\wordpress\wp-load.php');
 foreach ($posts as $post) {
 wp_insert_post($post);
 }
?>
```

It doesent show any error.

I tried to execute the script from the CMD, from Firefox and Chrome.

This is what I tried so far:

· Add *ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);*.

· Add *set_time_limit(0);* where the *wp_insert_post()* function is.

· Change  *max_allowed_packet* size in *my.ini*.

If we can't make this work I thought that I could do an INSERT TO, but with this the URLs won't be generated.

Thank you.

Comment: `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); ` may be too short for importing all posts( you're using several db connects for every post ). try `ini_set('max_execution_time', 30000);` or only `set_time_limit(0);` without ini_set. but it may not change your `php.ini` configs

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the second param to true  `wp_insert_post($post,true)` . You can see any errors . Encountered .